# zip mail attachment getting corrupt by sendmail

Tags: zip, sendmail

I'm trying send an email through sendmail with zip file attachment using below function. It's working fine with csv file, but a zip format of same csv is getting corrupted. Thanks in advance.

```
mailUsers()
{   
(
echo "From: ${mailfrom}"
echo "To: ${mailto}"
echo "Cc: ${mailcc}"
echo "Subject: ${EMAILSUB}"
echo "Mime-Version: 1.0"
echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"'
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
echo ""
echo "--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"

cat $outputBodyFile | sed -e "s%@SUMMARY@%`tr '\\n' ' ' < $sqlplusOutput`%" 

echo "--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"
echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$FILENAME"
echo ""
cat $FILENAME
) | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
LogMessage $logFile  "Mail Sent..."
}
```

Comment: Binary files need to be encoded into ASCII text for transfer via mail, e.g. using base64.   I recommend NOT trying to construct messages containing mime attachments yourself in a shell script, but to use either a language like perl or python with good library support for mail and mime, or an existing tool such as `mime-construct` (http://www.argon.org/~roderick/) (this is packaged for debian and probably other distros, otherwise you can get the source from the link), or `makemime` from the `maildrop` (http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) package.

Comment: For example: `mime-construct --subject "$EMAILSUB" --to "$MAILTO" --from "$mailfrom" --cc "$mailcc" --body $'optional plain text string message\n'  --attach "$FILENAME"`.   You can even attach multiple files of different types, each with different mime-types and encodings, you can specify those manually with command-line options or let `mime-construct` figure them out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The zip file is binary, the csv file is not. Email is not meant for binary files.

Add a header `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` and encode the zip file in base64. So change the lines for the attachment to

```
echo "--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw"
echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$FILENAME"
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
echo ""
base64 $FILENAME
```

There is also a binary transfer encoding defined, but it is optional and not all mail servers support it.

Comment: isn't closing boundary mandatory (e.g. last line should be `--GvXjxJ+pjyke8COw--` ) ?

Comment: @Archemar OP says that it worked for text files, might depend on the email client.

Comment: base64:  not found.